# Z transformation with $k$ from non-zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, transformation, z-transform

we known that $Z$ transformation of $f_k$ is defined as
$$F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k z^k$$

My problem is if $k$ starts from $m$, where $m >0$, then $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}f_{k+m} z^{k+m}$ is still equals $F(z)$, Is it correct?

Comment: I added trans. and z-trans. tag. Could you suggest to me another tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}f_{k+m} z^{k+m}$ still equal to $F(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k z^k$ ?

In general, no.

You have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}f_{k+m} z^{k+m}&=\sum_{p=2m}^{\infty}f_{p} z^{p} \quad (p:=k+m)\\\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}f_{p} z^{p}-\sum_{p=0}^{2m-1}f_{p} z^{p}\\\\
&=F(z)-\sum_{p=0}^{2m-1}f_{p} z^{p}.
\end{align}
$$

---

But you have

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{k=m}^{\infty}f_{k-m} z^{k-m}&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}f_{p} z^{p} \quad (p:=k-m)\\\\
> &=F(z).
> \end{align}
> $$